# JSON Schema get anyOf in a complex object with multiple arrays

Tags: json, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

I'm unable to find a solution for the following problem:

Given this input

```
{
  "grandParent": {
    "parent1": {
      "kids": [{
        "name": "David"
      }, {
        "name": "Josh"
      }]
    },
    "parent2": {
      "kids": [{
        "name": "Michael"
      }]
    },
  }
}
```

I'm trying to write a schema that will succeed if at least one of the kids' names (regardless of the parent) is "David" or "Kevin"

Here's the schema I tried:

```
{
  "properties": {
    "grandParent": {
      "additionalProperties": {
        "properties": {
          "kids": {
            "type": "array",
            "contains": {
              "properties": {
                "name": {
                  "anyOf": [
                    {
                      "type": "string",
                      "pattern": "David"
                    },
                    {
                      "type": "string",
                      "pattern": "Kevin"
                    }
                  ]
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

For some reason it still errors on the second parent, even though the first one qualifies under that rule.

https://www.jsonschemavalidator.net/s/QoSf6uIl

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of a way to do what you want with JSON Schema without modifying the data structure.

Schemas are applied to each instance location. There's no way to combine arrays from multiple object locations. The only way to do what you want would be to modify the data so that grandParents were also an array, allowing you to do `contains ... -> ... contains`.